# Delivery email in cakephp contact form

Tags: cakephp

everyone who can help me,  i am newer in CakePHP and i have problem with contact form, i followed this tutorial http://blog.jandorsman.com/2011/05/cakephp-contact-form-with-validation-rules/

but my inbox is empty :(
I recived message :
Your message has been sent. Thank you, we'll get back to you shortly.
but, no effects :(..
what is problem?

my controller:

```
<?php
class ContactsController extends AppController {
 var $components = array('Email');


 var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    function send() {



        if(!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Contact->set($this->data);

            if($this->Contact->validates()) {
                if(!empty($this->data['Contact']['company'])) {
                    $this->Email->from = $this->data['Contact']['company'] . ' - ' . $this->data['Contact']['name'] . ' <' . $this->data['Contact']['email'] . '>';
                } else {
                    $this->Email->from = $this->data['Contact']['name'] . ' <' . $this->data['Contact']['email'] . '>';
                }
                $this->Email->to = 'info@mycompany.com';
                $this->Email->subject = 'Website request';
                $this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message']);
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your message has been sent.');
                // Display the success.ctp page instead of the form again
                $this->render('success');
            } else {
                $this->render('index');
            }
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        // Placeholder for index. No actual action here, everything is submitted to the send function.
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Check your spam/junk folder lol

Comment: lol ;) checked, but nothing ;)

Comment: Check your Apache? error logs

Comment: your flash message is not dependent on actually sending the email - it is probably failing, with error messages, to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the mail actually sends anything.

```
if ($this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message'])) {
    // sent
} else {
    // not sent
    debug($this->Email);
    exit;
}
```

You are only checking that the record has saved. You can also put the email component in debug mode for more details.

Comment: thanks man, i will try now..
nothing, 
($this->Email->send($this->data['Contact']['message'])) this is true and i cant see debug of email...

Do I need to modify config/email.php.default ??

Comment: object(EmailComponent) { to => 'dino@premium-assistance.com'
from => 'JOHN COMPANY - MY NAME IS JOHN <roolex@gmail.com>'
replyTo => null readReceipt => null return => null cc => array()
bcc => array() date => null subject => 'Website request' headers => array() additionalParams => null layout => 'default'template => null lineFeed => '' sendAs => 'text' delivery => 'mail'charset => 'UTF-8' attachments => array() xMailer => 'CakePHP Email Component' filePaths

Comment: smtpOptions => array()
 textMessage => 'TEST DATA OF MY MESSAGE TEST TEST 1 2
'
 htmlMessage => null
 messageId => true
 settings => array()
 components => array()
 _header => array()
 _message => array()
}

Answer (score 0):

maybe to late and you got it going, but you need to add the components Email and Session

```
class ContactsController extends Controller {

var $components = array('Email', 'Session');

function send() {
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Contact->set($this->data);
```

.............

.............

.............

Check settings and enable the usage of templates in:  /app/Config/email.php

in the 'default' setting put your real email address to test for correct working!